# Mounting an S3 bucket onto a AWS Ubuntu instance issues

Tags: ubuntu, php5, amazon-s3, s3fs

i'm using s3fuse to mount an s3 bucket onto ubuntu, so that i can take advantage of the storage space.

here are some environment info:
**System Info**:
Linux ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx 2.6.38-8-virtual #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 04:06:34 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
**Distro Environment**
Ubuntu 11.04

when i run the following command:
~$ /usr/bin/s3fs serverlogs /mnt/s3
output:
s3fs: could not determine how to establish security credentials

i have the permissions set right, i not only have the .passwd-s3fs file in my /usr/home directory, but as well as my /etc folder.  i grabbed a library class to connect to the S3 with PHP and the credentials work.  Any ideas what might be causing this output?

thanks in advance.

Comment: i didn't mean to answer my own post, but this seemed to get the s3 mounted, though i could have swore i ran this command last night: "sudo /usr/bin/s3fs -o allow_other serverlogsbucket /mnt/s3/"  there is an added slash on at the end of the mount.  it could have been sleepy eyes that could have thought this command was run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

repost of my comment as the answer:

I didn't mean to answer my own post, but this seemed to get the s3 mounted, though I could have swore I ran this command last night:

`sudo /usr/bin/s3fs -o allow_other serverlogsbucket /mnt/s3/`

There is an added slash on at the end of the mount. It could have been sleepy eyes that could have thought this command was run.

Comment: This was exactly the solution for me, too.  Thank you so much for following up with a clear posting of the answer.